# How to install gcc-8 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gcc, 22.04

Since the apt sources in 22.04 doesn't include gcc-8, is there a good way to install it?

I have been googling all day for this..

Comment: Same problem here, I need it for cuda 10 because my nvidia 750M is no longer supported in CUDA 11. I downgrade to 20.04 ^_^'

Comment: Hi Cesar, my suggestion rn is to use nvidia-docker. Much easier compared to messing around with the dependencies tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to install gcc-8 and g++-8 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446863/trying-to-install-gcc-8-and-g-8-on-ubuntu-22-04)