# Seeking gcc-8 packages form Ubuntu22 on ARM (Mac)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, 22.04, gcc, arm

I have a Ubuntu22 version running on an arm architecture (Mac M2) and need to install an earlier version of the gcc compiler (Version 8).

I am sorry if this sounds stupid but I have so far only found cross-compiler gcc8 packages  which (I assume) are meant to run on intel and compile for arm. Is there a way to install gcc8 for arm specifically?

I know the packages are no longer in any ubuntu22 repository but can be found for ubuntu20. But I seem to be to stupid to transfer [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446863/trying-to-install-gcc-8-and-g-8-on-ubuntu-22-04) to my arm architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the equivalent URLs for gcc-8 packages, but for arm64, from the ports server.

```
sudo apt update
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/gcc-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/gcc-8-base_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/libgcc-8-dev_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/cpp-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
# libmpx2 omitted as it's not available for arm64
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/i/isl/libisl22_0.22.1-1_arm64.deb
sudo apt install ./gcc-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb ./gcc-8-base_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb ./libgcc-8-dev_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb ./cpp-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb ./libisl22_0.22.1-1_arm64.deb
```

```
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/libstdc++-8-dev_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/g++-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
sudo apt install ./libstdc++-8-dev_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb ./g++-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_arm64.deb
```

Comment: ty for the answer. That worked like a charm .

Comment: as a follow-up question: Can I somehow install the ubuntu-ports universe repository as a apt repository to pull from when I do normal apt installs? 

Comment: It's on by default when you use arm64 architecture.